# Initialising a postgresql database via a setup script in a VM using puppet

Tags: postgresql, vagrant, puppet

I want to run the following setup script to configure a postgresql database that's being deployed via a virtual machine, provisioned via vagrant using puppet:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

sudo su - postgres
createdb testdb

psql -s tm351test -c "create user test password 'test';GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE testdb TO test;"

touch /root/postgresql.done
```

My vagrant config takes the form:

```
package {
  [
    'postgresql',
    'postgresql-client'
  ]: ensure => latest;
}

file {
  '/root/postgresql.setup':
    source => 'puppet:///modules/infinite_interns/root/postgresql.setup',
    owner  => root,
    group  => root,
    mode   => '0744';
}

#TO DO - how do we guarantee the postgresql server is running and tools available?
exec {
  'setup-postgresql':
    cwd     => '/root',
    command => '/root/postgresql.setup',
    creates => '/root/postgresql.done';
}

service {
  'postgresql':
    ensure => running,
    enable => true;
}

Package['postgresql'] -> Service['postgresql']
```

How do I guarantee that that the postgresql server is installed and running, and the command line tools available, before running the config script?

I'm new to Puppet - does the Exec() **not run** if the created file `postgresql.done` exists?

I suspect that the `psql` command may also expect a confirmatory "return" to execute the command - how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an official [postgresql module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/postgresql) that can be easily installed:

```
puppet module install puppetlabs-postgresql
```

or adding following to your `Puppetfile`:

```
mod 'puppetlabs-postgresql'
```

The configuration might look like this:

```
  class { 'postgresql::globals':
    encoding => 'UTF-8',
    locale   => 'en_US.UTF-8',
    version  => '9.6',
  }->
  class { 'postgresql::server':
    ip_mask_deny_postgres_user => '0.0.0.0/32',
    ip_mask_allow_all_users    => '0.0.0.0/0',
    listen_addresses           => '*',
    version                    => '9.6',
  }

  postgresql::server::db { 'testdb':
    user     => 'test',
    password => postgresql_password('test', 'testpassword'),
  }

  postgresql::server::pg_hba_rule { 'allow connection from ...':
    description => "Open up PostgreSQL for access from test domain",
    type        => 'host',
    database    => 'testdb',
    user        => 'test',
    address     => '.testdomain.com',
    auth_method => 'md5',
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the postgres module https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/postgresql

Comment: Okay - so it's 3am and I can't figure out how to use it/include it. Suppose I am provisioning from: class myBoxes::box::pgtest { ..my bits..} and I want a db name testdb with user/password test/test. What do I use and where (I have mod 'puppetlabs/postgresql' in my puppetfile)